# How get response on get request in JSON format using Rest Assured

Tags: json, rest, api, rest-assured

I need get data in JSON format on get request, data should be the following format:

```
{
  "birth_date": "1980-01-01",
  "birth_place": "",
  "sex": "",
  "inn": "",
  "snils": "",
  "rezident": "0",
  "depend_count": null,
  "name": {
    "surname": "Заноза",
    "name": "Заноза",
    "patronymic": "Заноза"
  }
}
```

But data is returned in the following form, response as string:

```
{
  "birth_date" : "1980-01-01"
,
  "birth_place" : ""
,
  "sex" : ""
,
  "inn" : ""
,
  "snils" : ""
,
  "rezident" : "0"
,
  "depend_count" : null,
  "name" : {
    "surname" : "\u0417\u0430\u043D\u043E\u0437\u0430"
,
    "name" : "\u0417\u0430\u043D\u043E\u0437\u0430"
,
    "patronymic" : "\u0417\u0430\u043D\u043E\u0437\u0430"

  }
}
```

Code:

```
public static String getClientInfo(String clientId) {
   String response =  given().
          param("id", clientId).
          when().get("/services/clients").               
          then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().
          extract().body().asString();
          System.out.println("Response = " + response);
          return response;
}
```

How get JSON format on get request using Rest-Assured?

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet might help you.

```
public static String getClientInfo(String clientId) {
        Response response =  given().
                param("id", clientId).
                when().get("/services/clients");
        response.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
        System.out.println("Non pretty Response : " + response.body().asString());
        System.out.println("Pretty Response : " + response.prettyPrint().toString());
        return response.prettyPrint().toString().replace("\\", "");
    }
```